# ¿Cómo se traduciría "Qui m'aime me suive" del francés?

Tags: traducción, modismos

Hay una frase célebre del rey Felipe VI de Francia: "Qui m'aime me suive". Literalmente, me parece traducirse en "Quién me ame me siga", pero no estoy seguro si está bien así en español. Es ambiguo en francés si la frase usa el subjuntivo, no sé si el "quién" debe llevar tilde, y ¿tal vez se debe añadir "que", cambiar "amar" por otro verbo o hacer algún otro cambio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varias teorías acerca del origen de la frase, pero la que respecta al rey Felipe VI dice más o menos así:

> Tras el entronamiento de Felipe VI, el Conde de Flandes le pidió la ayuda de Francia para extinguir una revuelta que se había producido en sus tierras. Felipe, que apoyaba esta ayuda, pidió consejo a los barones del reino. Estos le aconsejaron esperar, pero Gautier de Chatillon, condestable de Francia, le dijo: "quien tiene buen corazón halla siempre tiempo para la guerra", a lo que Felipe respondió: "Qui m'aime me suive". La guerra fue declarada, los barones siguieron al rey y Felipe consiguió contener la revuelta. — [WR](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/qui-maime-me-suive.843326/)

Como traducción del fragmento histórico yo diría:

> Quien me ama, que me siga.

Se puede usar el subjuntivo (quien me ame, el que me ame, aquel que me ame), pero la versión con indicativo a mí me suena más tajante. Sea como sea, ambas son muy similares.

La partícula "que" no siempre es necesaria para construir un imperativo dirigido a terceras personas ("hágase la luz"; "tómese", "considérese" y otras expresiones en textos matemáticos; "sea pues"; "véase el párrafo siguiente", "no te quepa la menor duda", etc). Algunos gramáticos no consideran estas frases imperativas tanto como exhortativas o desiderativas, pero esa consideración no tiene reflejo en la sintáctica así que no hace falta explicarla. En este caso, hace falta usar la partícula *que*.

Según [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui_m%E2%80%99aime_me_suive), la expresión también se usa como frase hecha para invitar a otros a seguir a uno:

> **qui m’aime me suive**.
>   S'emploie pour inciter d'autres à prendre le même chemin que soi.

En ese sentido, "amar" me parece un poco fuerte. Yo diría, como traducción más o menos literal:

> El que esté conmigo, que me siga.
>   El que me apoye, que me siga.

Ninguna de las dos son frases hechas en español, pero se entienden y suenan natural.

Comment: No entiendo por qué en la primera traducción no usas el subjuntivo, pero en las dos últimas sí. A mí me suena mal con el presente de indicativo.

Comment: ¡Qué respuesta tan completa! Mil gracias, hoy aprendí algo. :)

Comment: @Jdamian En la última uso el subjuntivo porque  veo más "humilde" no dar por sentado  que alguien vaya a seguir al que lo dice. En la primera frase, el indicativo indica que sí hay alguien que ama al rey, a eso me refiero con que suena más tajante. A mí no me suena mal usar el indicativo, pero el subjuntivo también me suena bien.

Answer (score 0):

Quien me quiera que me siga.
La mejor opción.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.